# Python Handling Socketserver request in the Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

In the next examlpe I have Socket server handled in the thread. In the handle function we create Thread and pass *request* and client_*address*.
When we handle the request in run-method of the Thread it's only possible to receive data, but when I try to send somthing an Exception is raised ([Errno 9] Bad file descriptor)
What's wrong?

```
import SocketServer
import threading


class MyServerThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, channel, details):
        self.channel = channel
        self.details = details
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print 'Received connection:', self.details[0]
        self.channel.send('(Response)')
        print 'Received:', self.channel.recv(1024)
        self.channel.close()
        print 'Closed connection:', self.details[0]


class MyThreadedSocketServerHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        thread1 = MyServerThread(self.request, self.client_address)
        thread1.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer(('localhost', 8888), MyThreadedSocketServerHandler)
    server.serve_forever()


#---Client to test---
import socket

message = "(Request)"

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    sock.connect(('localhost', 8888))
    sock.send(message)
    data = sock.recv(1024)
    print 'Sent:     %s' % message
    print 'Received: %s' % data
finally:
    sock.close()




#Working example without "join"
import socket
import threading

class ClientThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, channel, details):
        self.channel = channel
        self.details = details
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print 'Received connection:', self.details[0]
        self.channel.send('message')
        print self.channel.recv(1024)
        self.channel.close()
        print 'Closed connection:', self.details[0]

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(('', 8888))
server.listen(5)

while True:
    channel, details = server.accept()
    ClientThread(channel, details).start()
```

Comment: Maybe client closes connection by the time you trying to send data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [ThreadingMixIn](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html#server-creation-notes):

```
from SocketServer import TCPServer, ThreadingMixIn

class MyServerThread(ThreadingMixIn, TCPServer): pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is:

```
thread1.start()
```

Above code is return immediately, MyServerThread.run() run in background. So MyThreadedSocketServerHandler.handle() return before MyServerThread.run() can be executed. After handle() function return, self.request will be close, your client will get nothing. When MyServerThread.run() is executed, self.request.send() will fail for the socket is closed.

So add:

```
thread1.join()
```

after start

Comment: Ok. It works now. But why does it work in the other example without join (I've started server in different way)? Look to updated question

Answer (score 0):

I think the probleme is that with your thread for handle the received data, your request is closed befor the thread can do anything with it.

for exemple, if u add a

```
thread1.join()
```

for your client look like this

```
    def handle(self):
        thread1 = MyServerThread(self.request, self.client_address)
        thread1.start()
        thread1.join()
```

you will don't have the error.

in fact, after the call for handle, the Handler close the connexion. and your probleme is that your thread try to deal with it AFTER it was closed.

i hope I have helped you and my poor english was not too hard to understand (i am french)